# List of codepages available in the Windows 7 system

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I need to fill a combobox with list of all codepages available in the Windows 7 system and show the default as a selected value.

Which way to get this list in WPF?

Comment: What issue? You've asked what codepages are available, but not said what problems you're having.

Comment: Unless you're dealing with some legacy code or application, and given the tags you've put on this my guess is you're not, you shouldn't be looking at codepages at all. You should be using unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Sorry about the earlier answer - I'd misread "Windows 7" as "Windows Phone 7".)

You can use [`Encoding.GetEncodings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getencodings.aspx) to find out all the encodings available. For each encoding, there are various "identifiers" in the properties - `CodePage`, `EncodingName`, etc.